# app deployed to heroku not stable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app deployed on heroku which uses postgres.  The app is not stable...works sometimes and sometimes gives the custom 500 page error.

Code that it is giving error on:

```
  def login
    session[:user_id] = nil
    if request.post?
      if @user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:userid],  params[:user][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
                if @user.stores.length > 0
            redirect_to(:controller => "admin", :action => "select_store")
          else
            redirect_to(:controller => "pages", :action => "mainpage")
          end
        else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid user/password combination"
      end
       end
  end
```

my model looks like:

```
  def self.authenticate(userid, password)
    user = self.find_by_userid_and_password(userid, password)
    user
  end
```

heroku logs says:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."userid" = E'sampleuser' AND "users"."password" = E'12345')  LIMIT 1):
  app/models/user.rb:7:in `authenticate'
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:6:in `login'
```

since it is an intermittent error i dont know how to fix it.  But is it possible to show the errors on the page?....is it possible to catch errors like these and then still proceed? what would be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to make custom find:

```
  def self.authenticate(userid, password)
    user = self.find(:first, :conditions => {:userid => userid, :password =>password})
    user
  end
```